# Getting relative path in Power Query using M-language

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

We all know the famous Excel formula to evaluate the current workpath:

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename");SEARCH("[";CELL("filename");1)-1)
```

My question is, is there any way to get the same result as the formula above (get the current path that the file/Excel is) but using only `M-language` or other workarounds?

Clarify that my question is merely curiosity, rather looking for a practical answer for a problem -the Excel formula works just fine for that!-.

Comment: Can you provide some data and expected output?

Comment: @DavideBacci Just edited my question. But the expected output would be the current path that the Excel is stored in. I'm not sure what do you mean by "data" in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this in Power Query. You could try putting the path in a cell in Excel and getting it that way though.

Comment: I'm aware of that workaround yes! But I was extremely curious if Power Query alone could do the task. Well! It's fair though. Thank you!